# Using html and css to produce a specific alignment

Tags: html, css

I need to generate the following in html (with css) for a project.

I have have used HTML over years, but how to generate a page with
these properties eludes me.

I have be trying to use postion absolute and relative, but can get the
following alignment to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
-----------------------  Centered Header Here ------------------------------

1000 Smith Street                                             Date: March 28, 2015
Houston, TX  77043                                       Invoice #:
Phone: 555-555-5000

BILL TO:
Mike Jones
10 Graylord
Houston, TX 77044

 ---------------- Table Starts Here ------
```

Comment: No disrespect but you have used html for years but can't center a header and build a table?? lol

Comment: "I have have used HTML over years" - lol so this question shouldn't be a big problem for you? And what can't you get to work?

Comment: You'll have to show your markup and what you've tried so far if you are expecting a useful answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far bro?? Please provide the codes or post a jsfiddle

Comment: Why not show us what you have so far, dude. The fact you use HTML for years doesnt make us any wiser. Ever thought about using a table to generate this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. A few very simple examples

old school nested tables

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Heading</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--- table for invoice info --->
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--- invoice info column 1 --->
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <!--- invoice info column 2 --->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--- content table --->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or via divs

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <h1>heading</h1>
</div>
<div style="float:left; clear:both;">
    <!--- invoice info column 1 --->
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <!--- invoice info column 1 --->
</div>
<div style="float:left; clear:both;">
    <!--- table --->
</div>
```